# Excel API error - System.AccessViolationException : Attempted to read or write protected memory

Tags: .net, excel, windows-10, ms-office, excel-addins

I am using Excel.PivotTables API in the below syntax in 2 different files. One of them works absolutely fine while the other file hits an error: "System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt" at the line:

```
 _pivotTable = pivotTables.Add(pivotCache, _chartsSheet.Range[$"$A$30"], "Samplexxx", Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

This error only occurs on Windows10. Both files work with no issues on Windows7.
Is there a workaround or a fix for this?
I did refer to other threads on this issue, but its not exactly the same.

Thank you!